# Ext GWT 2.2.6 :TabIndex of the selected tab in tabpanel

Tags: java, gwt, gxt

I am trying to create an listener for tabpanel on Onselect event when a tab is selected. And I using below code.

It always alerts as -1, when any tab is selected. Can anyone please suggest any input on this.

```
eventTab.addListener(Events.Select, new Listener<TabPanelEvent>() {
              public void handleEvent(TabPanelEvent be) { 
                       Window.alert(" selected tab index is"+be.getSelectedItem().getTabIndex()); 
                       } 
       });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GWT - You can get selected tab by using addSelectionHandler. Try this code,

```
tabPanel.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>(){
  public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event){
   int tabId = event.getSelectedItem();
   Widget tabWidget = tabpanel.getWidget(tabId);
 }
});
```

GWT EXT

```
    eventTab.addListener(Events.Select, new Listener<ComponentEvent>() {
      public void handleEvent(ComponentEvent be) {
         Window.alert(" selected tab index is"+ be.getTabIndex());
      }
    });
```

Comment: You are adding listener for single tab. so getting only one index.
Add listener to all tabs and add components based on that.